# sql server not in operation in linq to entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

```
IEnumerable<VPN_TASK> vpnTaskQuery = from p in dbContext.VPN_TASK 
                                     where !p.TASK_STATUS.contains("I_SUSPENDED" "I_TERMINATED", "Cancelled", "Rejected") 
                                     select p;
```

I need to remove task those taskstatus contains `("I_SUSPENDED" "I_TERMINATED", "Cancelled", "Rejected")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse `Contains`:

```
IEnumerable<VPN_TASK> vpnTaskQuery = from p in dbContext.VPN_TASK 
                                     where !(new [] {"I_SUSPENDED" "I_TERMINATED", "Cancelled", "Rejected"}).Contains(p.TASK_STATUS) 
                                     select p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var status = new[] { "I_SUSPENDED" "I_TERMINATED", "Cancelled", "Rejected" };

IEnumerable vpnTaskQuery = from p in dbContext.VPN_TASK where !status.Contains(p.TASK_STATUS) select p;
```